# What is a not-to-be-implemented interface good for?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I really wonder what can be [such an interface](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/tags/hamcrest-java-1.1/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/Matcher.java) used for. The purpose of the method called

```
_dont_implement_Matcher___instead_extend_BaseMatcher_
```

is crystal clear, but what's the purpose of the interface?

*If I didn't want people to implement an interface, I simply wouldn't provide any* - an abstract class does the job. Unless there's some hidden reason I can't see. Can anybody?

Answer (score 5):

Look to me like Matcher is an old interface that has been replaced by BaseMatcher but has not been removed to maintain compatibility with older versions.

edit:

The revision history seems to back this up: http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/diff?spec=svn46&r=46&format=side&path=/trunk/hamcrest-java/src/api/org/hamcrest/Matcher.java

Comment: Except that it wouldn't be, because of this new method.

Comment: @yshavit... compatibility for consumers rather than implementors

Comment: @Konstantin Komissarchik: Yes, *compatibility for consumers rather than implementors* is something I didn't think of. It could explain it, assuming any further development. But there's none, no additional methods in `BaseMatcher`, nothing since 6 years.